# MYSQL resource query

Tags: php, mysql

I firstly fetch the query from MYSQL database and email it to my mail

MYSQL

```
$sqll = "SELECT motheremail FROM family WHERE familyId = 1004";
            $email_message = mysql_query($sqll)or die(mysql_error());;
```

But As a message on email i get "Resource id #83" and not the thing that is in table

any ideas why?

Comment: `any ideas why` --- that always happens when people don't read documentation http://nz.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: mysql_query() returns a mysql resource object, that contains the query data (in most cases not just one row). Btw, google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the result of your query.

```
$sqll = "SELECT motheremail FROM family WHERE familyId = 1004";
$result = mysql_query($sqll)or die(mysql_error());

// Fetch the row from the result set
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['motheremail'];
```

Or if more than one row is expected, fetch them inside a `while` loop:

```
$sqll = "SELECT motheremail FROM family WHERE familyId = 1004";
$result = mysql_query($sqll)or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['motheremail'];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm Now I get nothing from the query even when there is something

Comment: If you get nothing, then there is no matching row. You'd get an error printed from `mysqL_error()` if something was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` doesn't return a string directly. You'd have to use something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `motheremail` FROM `family` WHERE familyId = 1004";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$message = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)['motheremail'];
echo $message;
```